# MongoDB log file

Tags: mongodb, logging

I'm having problems with my configuration log file. I'm trying to log all operations but the only ones that are saved are the   SERVER RESTARTED .
My configuration file:

```
##store data here
dbpath=C:\data\db

profile=2

##all output go here
logpath=C:\mongodb\log\mongo.log

logappend=true
##log read and write operations
diaglog=3
```

What am I missing?
and is there a way to configure mongo log file with java spring somehow (maybe xml)?

Answer (score 2):

In general you do **not** want to use the [`diaglog` configuration option](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#diaglog) as the diaglog binary files are both *very* verbose and also difficult to work with. With this setting enabled you will get a sequence of files in your `dbpath` directory named `diaglog.<time in hex>`. You can replay these files using the [`mongosniff`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongosniff/#bin.mongosniff) tool, but this approach is mostly intended for driver/server development rather than end user troubleshooting.

FYI, the `diaglog` option has actually been deprecated as at MongoDB 2.6 (ref: [SERVER-12149](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12149)).

To log queries you should instead be looking at the [Database profiler](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/) which can be enabled either globally (as you have done in your config with with `profile=2`) or per-database.

The profiling data will be saved in a capped `system.profile` collection with a default size of 1Mb per database. If you want to collect more history, you can create a larger `system.profile` collection.

Note that it is not recommended to run with profiling level 2 in production, as that will generate a write for every query to your database.

> is there a way to configure mongo log file with java spring somehow (maybe xml)?

I wouldn't expect a driver to have options to configure the MongoDB server.

You can, however, invoke the [`profile`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/profile/#dbcmd.profile) command via the Java driver to adjust profiling options at runtime.

For example, you could enable profiling level 2 with something like:

```
db.command(BasicDBObjectBuilder.start().add("profile", 2).get());
```